# Python turtle.ondrag not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I've been trying to make a paint program in Python Turtle and for some reason it won't work. I'm using the pen() tool and my code looks like this

```
from turtle import *
import random

pen()
bgcolor('black')
pencolor('white')
pen.ondrag(pen.goto)
listen()
mainloop()
```

I've look at this http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html and it says to type turtle.ondrag(turtle.goto) but since I'm using the pen it should work as pen.ondrag but it doesn't, so can someone please clear this up.

Thanks Jellominer

Comment: Please post the whole code. What is `pen`? Do you mean the method [`turtle.pen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.pen)? That isn't an object, and you can't use it with `goto` or `ondrag`.

Comment: The code works fine without the last 2 lines

Comment: @Jellominer To repeat what Kevin has said, you need to tell us what `pen` is. If you're referring to the method `turtle.pen`, it makes sense that it wouldn't have an `ondrag` attribute. It would help us help you if you could describe what your program is supposed to do.

Comment: ondrag is not a `pen` method, so `pen.ondrag` doesn't make much sense. `turtle.ondrag` is is different, it's finding ondrag in the turtle import. I think things will be much easier for you if you start by giving each separate object in your code a name to use:  like `screen = Screen()` and or `brush=Turtle()` so you can then say  `brush.ondrag(brush.goto)`

Comment: @Meep Tried what you said and the program runs but the turtle doesn't move to where I click.

Comment: @Asad im sorry i didn't understand the question. When I was watching some tutorials on how to use Python Turtle, they put pen() at the top and it still draws fine so it must refer to the Turtle.pen() method

Comment: The `turtle.pen()` (or `Turtle.pen()` if you `import *`) function is defined to, "Return or set the pen's attributes."  I.e. it isn't a *pen/turtle*, it's a utility function for accessing or setting the attributes of a pen/turtle.  A call to `turtle.Turtle()` or `turtle.Pen()` (or `Turtle()` or `Pen()` if you `import *`) returns a pen/turtle.  A call to `pen()` by itself does nothing of value.

Answer (score 0):

I will simplify and clarify the code given by the questionner:

```
from turtle import *

ts = Screen(); tu = Turtle()
ts.listen()
ondrag(tu.goto)
mainloop()
```

This works. You have to **click on the turtle** and drag it.

Comment: The command `.listen()` is necessary for keyboard events, not mouse events, so you don't need `ts`.  Also , you don't need `tu`  as you can simply say `ondrag(goto)` since you did `import *` and can use the default turtle.  Of course, this approach doesn't work very well.   But it's simple.

Comment: Actually, this code doesn't really work.  In the statement `ondrag(tu.goto)` you're talking about two different turtles, i.e. asking the default turtle to drag your turtle.  You can see this if you drag the turtle towards the corner of the window.  Then try to drag that same turtle again -- it won't work.  You have to go back to the non-moving turtle in the center of the window to drag the other turtle again.  This is what happens when you use `import *` -- you confuse the functional and OOP turtle interfaces.

Comment: I copied anew to a file and ran under Python 2 & Python 3 and I stand by my claim.  I'm running under Unix in a terminal window, are you using some other environment?  The `ondrag(tu.goto)` call involves two turtles, the `ondrag()` is a function that operates on the default turtle.  The `tu.goto()` invokes a method on a turtle you created.  Both are active on the screen.  See [Difference between turtle and Turtle?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42876725/5771269) for an explanation of this duality.  Did you try the exercise I described?  Did you not see two triangles after your initial drag?

Comment: OK, .listen() is not needed. But it does not produce an error and, most importantly, the code works! You

Answer (score 0):

First, `pen()` is not the function you want.  Second, although `Pen` is a synonym for `Turtle`, `pen` is not a synonym for `turtle`.  Here's how to go about using `ondrag()` if you'd like to use `Pen` instead of `Turtle`:

```
from turtle import Pen, Screen, mainloop

def ondrag_handler(x, y):
    pen.ondrag(None)  # disable handler inside handler

    pen.setheading(pen.towards(x, y))  # turn toward cursor
    pen.goto(x, y)  # move toward cursor

    pen.ondrag(ondrag_handler)

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')

pen = Pen()
pen.color('white')
pen.shapesize(2)  # make it larger so it's easier to drag

pen.ondrag(ondrag_handler)

screen.listen()
mainloop()  # screen.mainloop() preferred but not in Python 2
```

The `turtle.ondrag(turtle.goto)` makes for a nice short example in the documentation but in reality isn't practical.  You want to disable the event handler while handling the event otherwise the events stack up against you.  And it's nice to turn the mouse towards your cursor as you drag it.

Comment: I was really frustrated because the ondrag seems to work sometimes, and not work sometimes!  Finally I read the advice from @Apostolos that you must **click on the turtle**  if you click the screen, but not the turtle, the ondrag will not work!  Very counter intuitive. And no, there isn't any `screen.ondrag` so you're screwed unless you want to make the turtle huge so you can't help clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from turtle import *
ts = Screen()
ondrag(goto)
shapesize(10)
pensize(40)
speed(0)
mainloop()
```

I think this will surely work.

You can change the size and other things 
In here you are using the default turtle .

Sorry but you'll need to take care of the indentation