# What is the difference between turtle and Turtle?

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

How are **turtle** and **Turtle** different from each other in python version 2.7?

```
import turtle
star = turtle.Turtle()
for i in range(50):
    star.forward(50)
    star.right(144)
turtle.done()
```

Comment: turtle is a module that contains the class Turtle. If you are using Debian OS check in your default python libs folders. . e.g /usr/libs/python (version)/turtle

Comment: This isn't necessarily specific to Python 2.7.

Answer (score 7):

The turtle module is unusual. To make it easier for beginning programmers, all methods of the Turtle class are also available as top level functions that operate on the default (unnamed) turtle instance. All methods of the Screen class are also available as top level functions that operate on the default (sole) screen instance.  So both this:

```
import turtle

star = turtle.Turtle()  # turtle instance creation

for i in range(5):
    star.forward(50)  # turtle instance method
    star.right(144)  # turtle instance method

screen = turtle.Screen()  # access sole screen instance
screen.mainloop()  # screen instance method
```

and this:

```
import turtle

for i in range(5):
    turtle.forward(50)  # function, default turtle
    turtle.right(144)

turtle.done()  # function, mainloop() synonym, acts on singular screen instance
```

are both valid implementations.  Many turtle programs end up mixing the functional interface with the object interface.  To avoid this, I strongly recommend the following import syntax:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
```

This forces the object approach to using turtle, making the functional approach unavailable:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

star = Turtle()  # turtle instance creation

for i in range(5):
    star.forward(50)  # turtle instance method
    star.right(144)  # turtle instance method

screen = Screen()  # access sole screen instance
screen.mainloop()  # screen instance method
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, turtle is the package or library and Turtle() class constructor method used to instantiate the class.

Answer (score 1):

`turtle` is the module that you import while `Turtle` is that name of the class. Using `from turtle import *` removes the need for `turtle.Turtle`.

Comment: "Using `from turtle import *` removes the need for `turtle.Turtle`". It's not so simple. If you want multiple turtles, you need to use the instance mode. Secondly, `from turtle import *` pollutes the namespace with dozens of functions that can easily wreak havoc, causing namespace clashes with your local code. Best to [follow cdlane's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42876725/6243352) and only import `from turtle import Turtle, Screen`, which forces good practices.

Answer (score 1):

hope you have a good time!
"turtle" is actually the module that we use .
Turtle or we can say as turtle.Turtle is actually a object that you can move it change speed, color, shape and ....

here you can see an example:

```
enemy = turtle.Turtle(shape="rabbit.gif")
enemy.penup()
enemy.speed(0)
enemy.setposition(400, -180)
```

or another one:

```
player = turtle.Turtle(shape="turtle.gif")
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.left(90)
player.setposition(-400, -200)
```

or:

```
border = turtle.Turtle()
border.speed(0)
border.color("white")
border.penup()
border.setposition(-300, -300)
border.pendown()
border.pensize(3)
border.hideturtle()
```

hope it helps!

Comment: "`turtle.Turtle` is actually a object". `Turtle` is a type which you can create an object from by calling the initializer.

Answer (score 0):

`turtle` is the name of the package while `Turtle` is the name of the class.

An alternate way of importing the module would be:

`import turtle.Turtle`

Also, are you sure the last line is `turtle.done()` and not `star.done()`?

Comment: Or `from turtle import Turtle` but you will have to replace `turtle.Turtle` with just `Turtle` everywhere in the current module

Comment: `star.done()` would be an error, `turtle.done()` is valid.  The `done()` top level function is a synonym of the `mainloop()` top level function and doesn't apply to a turtle instance.  As a top level function ,`mainloop()` calls the  same named method of the singular screen instance.

Comment: I am sure about turtle.done() as done() comes under `_tg_utilities`

Comment: `import turtle.Turtle` doesn't work: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'turtle.Turtle'; 'turtle' is not a package`. Maybe you meant `from turtle import Turtle`.

Answer (score -1):

turtle is a method which contains a class which is noble Turtle