# Difference between turtle.listen() and screen.listen()

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, listen

Is there any difference between `window.listen()`, `screen.listen()`, and `turtle.listen()`?

I see them used differently in various programs but assume they can be called interchangeably.

Comment: i love the turtle library

Comment: Please provide more context.

Comment: did you read official documentation for turtle ?

Comment: If you see documentation and/or check source code (path: `import turtle ; print( turtle.__file__ )`) then you will see there is only one `listen()` but it can be accessible directly or with `getscreen()`, etc. Besides you can assing turtle to different variables `window`, `screen`, `hello_world` but it is still the same function.

Comment: i read the python api on turtle graphics...
say for example, you are creating a listener() for key events, i used both screen.listen and turtle.listen and both work. wondering if there's a difference...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read [Difference between turtle and Turtle?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42876725/5771269).  The short answer is that the turtle library provides two API's, a function-based one and an object-oriented one.  (Behind the scene, the function one is built atop the object one at load time.) The confusion begins when you mix the two.  My answer in the link explains one way to avoid doing so.

Answer (score 0):

### `turtle` and `screen` have separate inputs.

#### For example:

`turtle.onclick()` and `screen.onclick()` may seem the same but `screen.onclick()` is referring to the general window while `turtle.onclick()` is referring to the turtle module itself.

## Turtle

When calling `turtle.onclick()` you are activating the (`onclick`) function, to call your argument function whenever the user clicks specifically on the turtle object.

## Screen

When calling `screen.onclick()` you are activating the (`onclick`) function, to call your argument function whenever the user clicks anywhere on the window.

This is equivalent to `turtle.onscreenclick()` because `onscreenclick()` refers to the entire screen. Hence the name `screenclick` rather than just `click` which refers to the turtle object.

## Listen

So because `turtle` and `screen` have separate input functions, you'll need separate listening functions.

#### So

`turtle.listen()` listens for overall the entire turtle module's inputs, whilst `screen.listen()` listens for screen / window inputs.

Comment: "turtle.listen() listens for turtle inputs, whilst screen.listen() listens for screen inputs." is complete nonsense.  There is only one implementation of the `listen()` code.  `turtle.listen()` accesses that code as a (runtime generated) *global function* in the *turtle module*.  Whereas `screen.listen()` accesses that same code as a method of the singular screen instance, in this case stored in the arbitrarily named `screen` variable.  Turtle instances are, sadly, deaf.

Comment: @cdlane My answer is just a vague / simple version of what you said, although you were right about the last bit with Turtle instances, I'll correct for that.